# Get summary() of mytable from SQL database with R without writing it to my R session

Tags: sql, r, database, connection, summary

I want to get a table from SQL database with R, 
I can do that,

`df <- sqlQuery(channel, "select * from scheme.mytable1")`

But then I want to get the summary function of a table ( I want to see the tables summary)

`summary(df)`

I can do that with connecting to SQL db and taking the table to my R session 
(see it as a table in R console as df) and then get the summary(df)

But the thing I want to do is, to see its summary WITHOUT writing it to my R session
because the table is too big. (million columns) I can not write it to my R session.

But I want to see the summary of its columns only.

`summary(sqlQuery(channel, "select * from scheme.mytable1"))`

I want to do something like the above (but the code not work, just to show my purpose)

How can I do that? any package? any function ? deployer?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean millions of rows? I can't imagine you would want to call `summary` on a table with a million columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is leverage `dplyr::tbl` to create a remote table from the data source, and write your own `summary` method that does most of the computation on the DB. Here is what that might look like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# create a connection to table using dplyr, use dummy data 
# in memory SQLite here,in practice would do df <- tbl(con,  "mytable1")
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, ggplot2::diamonds, "diamonds")
diamonds_db <- tbl(con,  "diamonds")

# create custom summary method for the connection
summary.tbl_SQLiteConnection <- function(object, ...) {
  suppressMessages({
    nums <- object %>% 
      summarise_if(
        is.numeric, 
        # can put whatever functions here
        # these should work for most DBs
        list(Min = min, Max = max, Mean = mean)
      ) %>% 
      collect() %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
      mutate(name = stringi::stri_reverse(name)) %>% 
      separate(name, into = c("fun", "var"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(var, fun), stringi::stri_reverse) %>% 
      mutate(val = paste0(fun, ": ", round(value, 2))) %>% 
      split(.$var) %>% 
      lapply(`[[`, "val")
    other_nms <- object %>% 
      select_if(~!is.numeric(.x)) %>% 
      head(1) %>% 
      collect() %>% 
      names()
    other <- lapply(other_nms, function(x) {
      x <- ensym(x)
      object %>% 
        group_by(!!x) %>% 
        tally() %>%
        arrange(desc(n)) %>%
        # only show top 10 values
        head(10) %>%
        collect() %>% 
        mutate(tmp = paste0(!!x, ": ", n)) %>% 
        pull(tmp)
    })
  })
  names(other) <- other_nms
  lst <- c(other, nums)
  # format similar to summary.data.frame 
  mat <- matrix(NA_character_, max(sapply(lst, length)), length(lst))
  for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
    for (j in seq_along(mat[, i])) {
      mat[j, i] <- lst[[i]][j]
    }
  }
  colnames(mat) <- names(lst)
  rownames(mat) <- rep("", dim(mat)[1])
  structure(mat, class = "table")
}

summary(diamonds_db)
#> cut              color    clarity    carat     depth       price        table       x          y          z         
#> Fair: 1610       D: 6775  I1: 741    Min: 0.2  Min: 43     Min: 326     Min: 43     Min: 0     Min: 0     Min: 0    
#> Good: 4906       E: 9797  IF: 1790   Max: 5.01 Max: 79     Max: 18823   Max: 95     Max: 10.74 Max: 58.9  Max: 31.8 
#> Ideal: 21551     F: 9542  SI1: 13065 Mean: 0.8 Mean: 61.75 Mean: 3932.8 Mean: 57.46 Mean: 5.73 Mean: 5.73 Mean: 3.54
#> Premium: 13791   G: 11292 SI2: 9194                                                                                 
#> Very Good: 12082 H: 8304  VS1: 8171                                                                                 
#>                  I: 5422  VS2: 12258                                                                                
#>                  J: 2808  VVS1: 3655                                                                                
#>                           VVS2: 5066
```

I tried this on a table too big to fit in memory and it worked. This function doesn't *exactly* match what's given by `summary.data.frame`, but should be a start.

Comment: could you write this part in detail? copy_to(con, ggplot2::diamonds, "diamonds") what will I write instead of  ggplot2::diamonds, "diamonds"  ?

Comment: You don't need to do that, since the table already exists in your DB. You can start with `df <- tbl(con,  "mytable1")` to create the remote connection to your table

Comment: Does this method load the database in memory?

Comment: @JasonGoal no, it does not